# Trying to get multiple name values from a slicer

Tags: vba, excel

So I would like to retrieve the selected items from my "Department" slicer and store them in a string. However When I test this I only get the last item and its not even one selected. This works great for setting the DepartmentX slicer with the same items from Department however I would like to store only the selected items in a string. Any help would be greatly appreciated

here is what I have so far

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

   Dim PT1 As PivotTable, PT2 As PivotTable
   Dim slc1 As Slicer, slc2 As Slicer
   Dim slcCache1 As SlicerCache, slcCache2 As SlicerCache
   Dim slcItem1 As SlicerItem, slcItem2 As SlicerItem
   Dim slicer_data As String    

If Sh.Name = "GP YTD - Tooling (FYE 2016)" Then

   Set PT1 = Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables
("PivotTable2") '(1)
   Set slc1 = PT1.Slicers("Department") '(1)
   Set slcCache1 = slc1.SlicerCache

   Set PT2 = Sheets("Sheet2").PivotTables
("PivotTable3") '(2)
   Set slc2 = PT2.Slicers("DepartmentX") '(2)
   Set slcCache2 = slc2.SlicerCache
   slcCache2.ClearManualFilter

   For Each slcItem1 In slcCache1.SlicerItems
       slcCache2.SlicerItems(slcItem1.Name).Selected = slcItem1.Selected    
       slicer_data = slcItem1.Name

       Application.EnableEvents = True            
   Next slcItem1 

   MsgBox "Selected" & slicer_data        
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Modify the last line of `slicer_data = slcItem1.Name` to `slicer_data = slicer_data  & slcItem1.Name`. **Or** , if you want to add a `;` in the middle, you can also `slicer_data = slicer_data  & slcItem1.Name & ";"`

Comment: That works but now its giving me all of the items even if they are not selected. @ShaiRado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the last part to this:

```
   For Each slcItem1 In slcCache1.SlicerItems
       slcCache2.SlicerItems(slcItem1.Name).Selected = slcItem1.Selected    
       If slcItem1.Selected Then slicer_data = slicer_data & "," & slcItem1.Name

       Application.EnableEvents = True            
   Next slcItem1 

   MsgBox "Selected" & Mid$(slicer_data, 2)
```